# Can an irrational number have a finite number of a certain digit?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

This question came up because I was wondering the following: If the digits of PI are placed in ascending order, what is the <insert-large-finite-number-here>th digit?

I believe that the answer is 0, but I am not sure. The reason why I'm not sure is dependent on the answer to whether an irrational number can have a finite number of a certain digit. If this is the case, then it is conceivable that there could be a finite number of zeros. Taking an example, let us say that we are going to encode every digit of PI through the function $$ f(x) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
10+x,\quad when \quad x≠0\\ 
99,\quad when \quad x=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$ That is, for example if I am encoding the digits of $20$, then I'd replace the $2$ with $f(2)$ and the $0$ with $f(0)$ I'd get, as my end result, $1299$. This mapping function seems to totally eliminate zeros from the answer. By doing the same thing to PI, I can totally eliminate its zeros. It also seems conceivable that I can still generate a unique mapping if I apply the function to digits only after the first zero.

**So**: does my argument hold water? Is it possible to turn an irrational number into one with a finite number of a certain digit? Additionally, is it possible to prove whether an arbitrary irrational number has a finite number of a certain digit?

Comment: So You are in fact asking: does every irrational number...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number $0.010010001000010000010000001\ldots$ is irrational and has **no** instances of any digit other than $0$ and $1$. More generally, pick any two digits $d$ and $e$, and form the number

$$0.\mathrm{dedeedeeedeeeedeeeeed}\dots\;;$$

it never becomes periodic, so it’s irrational. Of course one can insert any finite string of digits between the decimal point and the expansion of an irrational number and still have an irrational number, e.g., $0.345345010010001000010000010000001\ldots$.

Comment: I think the OP meant something like $0.8787100100010000\cdots$. There the $8$ and $7$ occur only twice. Basically we want a sum of a rational plus a "lacunary" irrational, I guess.

Comment: @Peter: I thought it obvious that one could prefix any finite string, but I’ll add that.

Comment: But is it possible to prove whether or not an arbitrary irrational number has a fixed number of a certain digit?

Comment: @Maz: Not in general, no.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For an extreme example, let $a$ have decimal expansion
$$0.101001000100001000001\dots.$$
The number of $0$'s between consecutive $1$'s is $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, and so on. Thus the decimal expansion of $a$ cannot be ultimately periodic, and therefore $a$ is irrational.

By the way, it is not known whether the decimal expansion of $\pi$ has infinitely many $0$'s. The same applies to any other digit.

Comment: Of course one can add any finite string of numbers before the "binary" sequence to fulfill the OP's request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and without giving you another example let me instead give you the vocabulary.  An irrational number is said to be a "normal" number if each digit, 0 through 9 in base-10, and in each base numbering system, occurs in equal quantities.  All irrational numbers must contain at least two unique digits in infinite quantities, but not necessarily in equal proportion.

Comment: Doesn't [normality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) require that each string, not just each digit, be uniformly distributed? Does requiring that each digit be uniformly distributed in EVERY base imply that every srtring is also uniformly distributed?

Comment: Actually at least two must be in the same quantity (in the same way that there are as many even numbers as natural numbers.) Assume that all the digits occur a different number of times. Than one will occur the most. Since the number of digits in an irrational number is $\aleph_0$ the sum of the occurrences will be that. For this to be true, the greatest one must be $\aleph_0$. Then the others must be less, and therefore finite in occurrence. They will run out eventually, and then it will just the greatest occurring digit, which makes it rational, which is a contradiction!

Comment: Therefore, two must occur the same number of times, $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @QuinnCulver It turns out that the answer is yes, but this is a non-trivial result - I suggest looking at section 3.5 in volume 2 of Donald Knuth's _The Art of Computer Programming_, specifically Theorem C there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn’t necessarily answering this question, but I use this fact in answering another question, but the post got deleted, so I will explain how I use it.

The question that was asked was if it is possible for the sum of the reciprocals of digits of an irrational number to ever converge.

Here is my explanation to that:

Well no, think about it like this, unless there are only finitely many numbers which are not zeroes then the sum will contain infinitely many numbers of at least $\frac{1}{9}$. Then it will just be summing up an infinite number of a constant and will be infinity.  However, if there are only finitely many nonzero digits, then the digits of the number can be truncated, and therefore it is not an irrational number, because it can be written as a fraction with 10^N as the denominator where N is the last nonzero digit.

Also, there is a theorem in Calculus that states that if the terms of a series do not converge to 0 then the series diverges.

Which indirectly talks about this question.  I mention that if there are only finitely many of nonzero digits then the number is not irrational, this is true, but not necessarily unique to zero, because if there is only one value in the digit sequence infinitely many times then it will eventually repeat itself and will not be irrational, so we need two different values in the digit sequence infinitely many times as the previous posters have mentioned.